# Power supply voltage drop with load

Tags: power-supply, voltage, dc, repair

I'm trying to fix a old soviet power supply and I think it is a switched-mode power supply. When I plug it into the wall it makes a high pitched sound around every one second. The output voltages are normal when there is no load but when a load is attached the voltages drop to zero. Also when the load is attached and the high pitched sound is heard the voltages rise a few volts and drop to zero almost instantly. The power supply also does not use any controllers.

[image: pcb front side]

[image: pcb back side]

[image: psu]

Comment: Welcome! If you can’t find a schematic for it, you need to trace out parts of it. Post oscillograms of relevant nodes.

Comment: What is the expected voltage and current out?  If it's supplying (e.g.) anode voltage to a CRT it wouldn't provide much current.

Comment: The voltages are +12, -12, +33 and +120. Current I'm not sure. Also found the schematic for the psu but it has some differences to the actual thing.

Comment: It sounds like an over current protection (or another protection) is triggering off.